# Способы анимации "display: none" без JS

Tags: css, css3

Сделаю минимальный пример:

```css
input, div {
  display: none;
}

label:before {
  content: 'Показать';
}

#toggle:checked + label:before {
  content: 'Скрыть';
}

#toggle:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle"></label>

<div>Скрытый контент</div>
```

Вопрос именно про `display: none`, поэтому способы прозрачности и нулевой высоты взамен данного свойства не предлагать. Анимация конечно же может содержать в себе `opacity`, `height`, `width`, `transform` и прочие стили. При помощи JS, особенно с помощью jQuery, это тоже без труда реализуется, но, вопрос именно по CSS.

Если таковых нет, поделитесь, что используете и почему? Например, при сокрытии и отображении подробной информаци или обрезки текста.

Comment: свойство `display` анимировать нельзя, оно не числовое, как вы представляете его анимацию? А все плавные скрытия, в том числе "при помощи JS, особенно с помощью jQuery" как раз и происходят через анимацию прозрачности, высоты и т.д. и установки `display: none` по окончанию анимации

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич я знаю, как минимум одно, решение для плавной анимации появления или сокрытия элемента в данной конструкции при помощи `keyframes`. К слову, анимировать само свойство я и не предлагал, то, что оно работает как "тумблер" все прекрасно знают. Мне больше были интересны идеи реализации.

Comment: как это вы не предлагали, если вы написали: `Вопрос именно про display: none, поэтому способы прозрачности и нулевой высоты не предлагать.`? При помощи `keyframes` или js - это не принципиально, суть в том, что всё равно анимируется числовое значение прозрачности, размера или позиции. И, если `то, что оно работает как "тумблер" все прекрасно знают` - в чём тогда заключается вопрос?

Comment: Речь шла о том, что у элемента должен присутствовать `display: none`, так как почти все решения подробного рода заключаются в том, чтоб убрать display и скрыть его при помощи `opacity` и `height`, к которым анимация прикручивается без особого труда. Вопрос в том, как сделать плавность появления, когда у элемента есть переключение с `display: none` на `display: block`.

Comment: Вопрос дополнил немного, чтоб не было путаницы.

Comment: Ответ - никак. Переделайте свою верстку и не ломайте голову.

Comment: А как по Вашем должна выглядеть такая анимация? почему не схлопывание в точку как при выключении кинескопа?

Comment: Без `height` или js - никак

Answer (score 3):

«Вопрос в том, как сделать плавность появления, когда у элемента есть переключение с display: none на display: block.» Пример с `display: none` на `display: block` с методом `keyframes`:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label:before {
  content: 'Показать';
}

#toggle:checked + label:before {
  content: 'Скрыть';
}

#toggle:checked ~ div {
  animation-name: open;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
#toggle:not(:checked) ~ div {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes open {
  0% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle"></label>

<div>Скрытый контент</div>
```

PS: лично я использую метод `toggle` на JS/jQuery - добавление/удаление дополнительного класса и комбинирую его с CSS так как хочу. Если на чистом CSS, то данный пример. В остальном зависит от идеи, конкретики того, что и как нужно, метод реализации - уже второй вопрос.

Comment: Я бы, например, и рад помочь Вам с репутацией, но автор вопроса однозначно написал, что вариант с нулевой высотой не рассматривается. А Вы всё равно нулевую высоту предлагаете :(

Comment: Ok.  Подправлю скоро.

Comment: Я удалил вашу просьбу из ответа, тем самым помог вам не заработать ешё минусов, к которым она бы без сомнений привела. Причём, не зависимо от качества ответа.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо. Отредактировал код, сделал пример с кейфреймом. ;-)

Comment: @humster_spb Благородный друг, отредактировал я свой ответ. Теперь он в тему.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev, плюсанул :)

Comment: @humster_spb взаимно.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev Поддержал вашу репутацию, старайтесь её не терять. Будте просто более лаконичны давая ответ.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо большое. Очень приятно. Можете полагаться на меня.

Comment: а как сделать что бы блок был изначально открыт